# Regex Match all instances of [ab_23] in a string

Tags: regex

I am trying to match all instances of [ab_456] where the numbers can be any digits and any amount in a string.

I have almost got it working with

```
[[ab_\d+\]]*\]
```

but this is also matching [ddf**444]** this part of this string and I cant work out why.

As I am trying to match square brackets I am not sure how they are working in my regEx as I was using trial and error to get it working and now have got a bit lost!

Comment: Did you mean `\[ab_\d+]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - you need to escape the closing `]`... but I believe you're correct

Comment: @freefaller No, it is not inside  a character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - fair enough... every day's a school day!

Comment: @Bex - I would recommend https://regex101.com - it's a great testing tool, which gives both an explanation of the pattern you've entered and the ability to check it against text. You can also choose which platform the regex needs to work against (javascript, .NET, etc)

Comment: @freefaller thanks, thats what I have been using, but I was getting lost !

Comment: @Bex - understandable. Regex can be a bit of a mind-#*%$ - I've been using it for years, and only learnt today you don't need to escape the closing `]`. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with `[]` it matches with ANY character inside, you probably want to use `()` which are for capture groups, but maintain specific order `(\[ab_\d+\])`

or omit `()` and just have `\[ab_\d+\]`

Comment: "use `()` for specific order"... can you explain what you mean by "specific order"?  I was always under the impression they were for capture groups

Comment: @freefaller yes, capture groups but contents are more of specific order compared to `[]` which is any order

Comment: without the brackets this is perfect! Thank you.
Are the \ escaping the square brackets?

Comment: But are they not always in the specific order without `()`?  Edit: I'm not criticising... this is purely out of interest, in case I'm doing regex wrong.

Comment: @freefaller no they are, but based on OP original regex with `[]` I assumed a misunderstanding about `[]` vs `()`. As I mentioned you can omit them

Comment: @Bex yes, escape `[`

Comment: ok - fair enough, although I would counter that stating round brackets are `for a "specific order"` is misleading. But I'll leave it there, I'm not trying to start an argument